# Is uncountable transcendental-additions enough to make $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ and then consider "adding" a transcendental $\zeta$ to it, while still retaining the field axioms (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$).

We could add another transcendental in an obvious extension to make yet another subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ - my question is this:

**Does adding an uncountable number of transcendentals to $\mathbb{Q}$ necessarily make it into $\mathbb{R}$?** Or could we add some uncountable subset of the transcendentals, such that the resultant field is not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Equivalently: does there exist an uncountable proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Not quite equivalent - I'm familiar with the fact that there exist uncountable subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ just by "adding" any compact Cantor set of Hausdorff-dimension 0. This is specifically about adding transcendentals.

Comment: @IskyMathews:  But Nate Eldredge specified that it must be a subfield, so must be closed under both addition and multiplication.  We may wind up adding in algebraic numbers as well.  Did you want to avoid that?

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry, I meant subfields.

Comment: Your example $\{n\mid \exists a,b\in \mathbb{Q}, n = a+b\zeta\}$ does not satisfy the field axioms (at least if you mean to use the standard multiplication). It is not closed under multiplication and division. You need to consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ consisting of all rational functions of $\zeta$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: Thanks! I've never seen this "$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$" notation before.

Comment: Btw, I agree with Ross that Nate's question is equivalent to yours as you've stated it in the OP. Since the set of algebraic elements of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable (this was the original context for Cantor's naming the distinction between countable and uncountable infinities in fact), any uncountable subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily contains uncountably many transcendentals. So an uncountable proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ is precisely a field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and uncountably many transcendentals that is not all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, you want to add transcendentals and *only* transcendentals?  In other words, you want an uncountable subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains no algebraic irrationals?

Comment: To be clear, when you refer to "transcendentals", you mean real numbers that are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: To specify Eric Wofsey's comment : is the new real you add transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, or over the previous field you built ?

Comment: I wanted to argue that you could by listing all the transcendentals in order, then adding alternate ones and closing under arithmetic.  Each closure only adds countably many new reals.  I wanted to say since you skipped uncountably many there must be some that didn't get added by the closures, but I believe that approach does not work.

Comment: @Max: I originally meant a transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, but does much change if it's over the previously built field? It seems an interesting question to ask.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: Thanks for pointing that out - I'm a bit slow at times!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make (a field isomorphic to) $\mathbb C$ from $\mathbb Q[i]$ by adjoining $2^{\aleph_0}$ independent transcendentals *and taking the algebraic closure*. Easy-peasy.

$\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$ is not so simple a matter.

If you just take $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ you don't get any $\sqrt[3]\zeta$, even though all reals have cube roots. You will need to do something additional to make it exist. Adjoining more *independent* transcendentals will not do, because if they can create $\sqrt[3]\zeta$, they were not algebraically independent from $\zeta$ in the first place.

Be sure not to do anything as crude as requesting an algebraic closure while doing this, because you don't want to get any $\sqrt{-1}$.

Because positive reals can be characterized *algebraically* as "all the squares of nonzero reals", simply knowing the *field* operations of $\mathbb R$ is enough to reconstruct the *ordering* of $\mathbb R$. This means that if you succeed in constructing $\mathbb R$ by somehow "adding" transcendentals, the resulting structure will determine exactly how each of your transcendentals compares to each rational -- that is, you will end up having determined *which real it is*. And that means that you need to make a lot of decisions along the way that reach farther than "here is another transcendental, same as all the other ones".

**Conversely:** By Zorn's lemma, $\mathbb R$ has a maximal algebraically independent subset -- a *transcendence basis*. Every real number is root in a polynomial whose coefficients are finite rational polynomials of the basis elements, in an "essentially unique" way.

If you take any proper subset of the transcendence basis -- which may well be $2^{\aleph_0}$-sized -- and take all real roots of polynomials with coefficients that are rational polynomials of the selected elements, then you get a field that probably matches your intuitive idea of "adding" $2^{\aleph_0}$ transcendentals. It will not be all of $\mathbb R$, and not even isomorphic it $\mathbb R$. Its field structure *alone* will encode exactly which of the reals are missing.

On the other hand, you can also (in one sense) "go too far" and add *too many* transcendentals, getting a [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) that properly extends $\mathbb R$. (For example, adjoin an infinitesimal element using a model-theoretic compactness argument, possibly followed by repeating the above construction to select exactly how many supernumerary independent transcendentals you want). Or even one that is neither a subfield nor an extension of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't think OP has in mind abstractly adjoining algebraically independent elements.  Instead, I believe they just mean to consider a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which is generated by uncountably many transcendental numbers.  And their question is not whether $\mathbb{R}$ can be built in this way, but whether such a subfield must always be equal to $\mathbb{R}$ itself rather than being smaller.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I hope the addition addresses that.

Comment: An amazing answer! Could you expand upon the "transcendence basis" idea? You say that the set of numbers that are roots of polynomials whose coefficients are each polynomials of members of the basis is $\mathbb{R}$, but why is this true? Also could you expand upon or link to something that does about the "going too far" idea? I'm not very used to these ideas.

Comment: @IskyMathews: If there was any real number that was _not_ a root of such a polynomial, then it would (by definition) be algebraically independent of the transcendence basis -- so we could add it to the transcendence basis and get at larger algebraically independent subset, contradicting that the basis was explicitly chosen (using Zorn's lemma) to be _maximal_.

Comment: @IskyMathews: For the "going-too-far" idea, one can use the [upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) to get a real closed field $K$ that properly extends $\mathbb R$. Then, for example, select a $\zeta\in K\setminus\mathbb R$ and consider all the elements of $K$ that are roots of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R(\zeta)$. You get a real closed field that has "one more transcendental" than $\mathbb R$ has.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Re: using the upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, I thought this was a statement on models of first-order theories. What is our theory here? Are we saying that we axiomatise the notion of being a real-closed-field-that-contains-$\mathbb{R}$-as-a-subfield in first-order sentences in the language of Field Theory and then, seeing that there exists an infinite model (i.e. $\mathbb{R}$), we apply LS? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: @IskyMathews: More generally the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem is a statement about _first-order structures_. We can view $\mathbb R$ as a structure over the language $\{0,1,{+},{\cdot},{<}\}$ and apply the theorem to find an elementary extension of larger cardinality. (The _proof_ of this involves defining a new language with a constant symbol for each real, and considering the complete theory of $\mathbb R$ in this language -- which it sounds like you are indeed proposing here. Note that the theory does not need to be recursively axiomatizable).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks! You've been very helpful - these are amazing and quite exciting ideas. I'd never heard of algebraic independence, which seems to strengthen linear independence in an extremely interesting way. I'll have to read more Field Theory!